# Using PHP Cookies Over Session_start()

Tags: php, cookies

I want to move over to using Cookies for my authentication ,I have come up with the following code  and will be looking to impliment something like this within my `user_check.php` page.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$ClientIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());

$LoginAudit = $Con->prepare("INSERT INTO loginaudit ('ID', 'emailaddress, 'date') VALUES ('', '$username', '$date'");
$LoginAudit->execute();
setcookie("LoginAuthentication", $username , time()+3600);
header("location:member_area.php");
```

And my script to check whether the cookie has been set?

```
setcookie("LoginAuthentication", $username , time()+3600);

if (!isset($_COOKIE['LoginAuthentication']))
{
    /// Re-direct To Main Menu
    break; 
}
```

I can't figure out why my cookie LoginAuthentication is not being picked up by my website script and auto-logging in?

Comment: Cookies are only sent with the rest of the HTTP headers, so the page has to complete the request before `setcookie` takes effect.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Could you point me into the right direction to properly create and check for Cookies within PHP?

Comment: So if I create a cookie on my system with the key `LoginAuthentication` I'm logged in? Great! link please.

Comment: @user1902584 there needs to be some trigger for creating the cookie.  That same trigger should log the user in irrespective of whether there actually is a cookie; the cookie is used to log them in automatically when they visit again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cookies for this is a very bad idea as cookies are editable and/or can be created at any time with arbitrary information in them (as noted by PeeHaa).

You should be looking at PHP **sessions**.
with PHP sessions all variables are stored on the server and linked to a session ID.  This session ID is created at the start of each session and stored (usually) in a cookie.

This tends to be a much more secure method as the specific session ID is unique and no data (other than the session ID) is stored client-side.

Refs:

- http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php
- http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php